# Replacing multiple images with their src attribute using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a variable `myvar = document.getElementById('myid').innerHTML` that I would like to replace all of the images in with their corresponding src attribute using JavaScript.

**EDIT:** Sorry for the confusion! I was trying to be succinct, time being precious and all - apparently I failed.

To borrow from Jon's interpretation:

I want to store all elements with the id of `myid` in `myvar` and then iterate through them to change all of them to plain text - the plain text being the value of their `src` attributes.

Here is an example of what I would like to achieve.

I start with something like this:

```
<img src="someimage.png"><br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
<img src="anotherimage.jpg"><br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

And it would translate to:

```
someimage.png<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>
anotherimage.jpg<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

Comment: You want what??? replace with what?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to store all elements with the id of `myid` in `myvar`, and then iterate through them to change all of their `src` attributes. Is that correct?

Comment: I've tried a number of things I thought might work, but deleted when they didn't. My most recent attempt used a for loop and replaceChild - either this was completely the wrong direction or I wasn't using it correctly. My best friend, Google, didn't seem to have an answer to my question this time either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems everyone missed what you were asking, perhaps you've "clarified" the question. This should suit:

```
var image, images = document.images;
var i = images.length;

while (i--) {
  image = images[i];
  image.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(image.src), image);
}
```

It will replace all the images in the document with a text node of their src property value. Note that as you replace each element, the *images* collection will get shorter, hence the backward loop. You could also do:

```
while (images.length) { 
  image = images[0];
  image.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(image.src), image);
}
```

If you want to restrict it to just the images inside a paricular element, get a reference to the element and create *images* as a NodeList using `element.getElementsByTagName('img')`;

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you are trying to do, but if you want the `<img>` under your variable use this:

```
var images = myvar.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
    images[i].src = "foo"; // changes the src of the image.
}
```

I hope it helps. next time ask a more clear question...

Comment: There is a `document.images` collection that is a little more convenient than using `getElementsByTagName`.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what in the world your talking about so i am just going to suggest using jQuery (since its easy) and do whatever you want to whatever your asking.

```
$.each($("img", $("#yourTargetDivOrBlankForBody"), function() {
    var $img = $(this);

    $img.attr("src", blahl balh);

    //Any other operations.
});
```

Comment: The above answer is better, its not using jQuery :)  But i still love jQuery

Comment: :) with jQuery it could even simpler then your answer... ``$('img', myvar).attr('src', "foo");``

Comment: @Michael - Mark did ask how to preform this in *Javascript*, not jQuery though.

Comment: @gdoron even though i upped you, he may want to do something specific for each element.

Comment: @JonMcIntosh jQuery is javascript :) (to be technical)

Comment: @Michael ofcourse jQuery is Javascript, but if his question isn't tagged with jQuery, and his code isn't written with jQuery, then chances are he's not going to expect an answer in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

New browsers...

```
[].slice.call(element.querySelectorAll('img')).forEach(function(img) {
    img.src = 'new url';
});
```

Older browsers...

```
var imgs = element.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (var i = 0, length = imgs.length; i < length; i++) {
    imgs[i].src = 'new url';
}
```